# Tables from markdown to Word looks unformatted

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, flextable

I am trying to export tables from R to Word using R-markdown via huxtable package but it looks unformatted. After knitr, RStudio launchs Word on Read only mode or Compatibility mode and tables looks pretty: 
[image: Looks good in read only mode]

but when I re-open MS Word in normal mode, the tables looks unformatted:
[image: Table looks ugly]

```
---
title: "Prueba"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
require(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
require(RODBC)
require(data.table)
library(huxtable)
library(flextable)
```

Loren ipsum...

```
tabla1 <- data.frame(mes = seq(1:4),
                     estado = 'observación',
                     valoracionesPorMes = seq(1:4))

tabla1 %>%
  bind_rows(., tibble(valoracionesPorMes = sum(.[["valoracionesPorMes"]]))) %>%
  as_hux(add_colnames = TRUE) %>%
  set_bold(nrow(tabla1)+2,1:ncol(tabla1),T) %>%
  set_bold(1,1:ncol(tabla1),T) %>%
  set_bottom_border(1,1:ncol(tabla1),1) %>%
  set_align(0:nrow(tabla1)+2, 1:ncol(tabla1), 'center') %>%
  set_width(100) %>%
  set_col_width(0.25) #%>%
  # huxtable::as_flextable()
```

I am using huxtable because I need to knitr to Word and looks suitable option to add format to tables, and total sums rows.
I know I could reformat in Ms Word but this is a flow with multiple tables, it is not suitable because it is a task that will be repeated many times.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `set_width()` and `set_col_width()` lines. You'll then get a reasonable width by default.